# How to get exact web socket url of my node app on Heroku

Tags: node.js, swift, heroku, websocket, socket.io

I followed a tutorial to host a chat app backend with node.js on heroku. The source is available [here](https://github.com/yigitserin/NodeChatApp/tree/master/server).

It is currently hosted on Heroku and works fine at the moment. The url is [here](https://shielded-everglades-33427.herokuapp.com/).

My question is how to connect this web socket on my mobile app? What is the exact url to the socket?

Using `https://shielded-everglades-33427.herokuapp.com/` or `ws://shielded-everglades-33427.herokuapp.com/` did not work.

I am using an iOS app with `Socket.IO-Client-Swift` library to test the socket and the relevant part is here:

```
func connectToSocketUI(){
        let socketURL = URL(string: "ws://shielded-everglades-33427.herokuapp.com:443")!
        let manager = SocketManager(socketURL: socketURL)
        let socketIO = manager.defaultSocket

        socketIO.on(clientEvent: .connect) { (data, ack) in
            print("Connected to Socket.io")
        }

        socketIO.on(clientEvent: .disconnect) { (data, ack) in
            print("Disconnected to Socket.io")
        }

        socketIO.on("newMessage") { (data, ack) in
            print(data)
        }

        socketIO.connect(timeoutAfter: 3) {
            print("Error")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Since your Heroku app is served over https, you should be using wss://

Try this:

wss://shielded-everglades-33427.herokuapp.com/